# Ruby on Rails - JQuery in AJAX pagination not running

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

Hey guys I'm trying to implement AJAX pagination and I've been all over railscasts examples.

I have this code in application.js

```
$(function() {
  $("#entidades .pagination a").live("click",function(){
    alert("ajax!");
    $.getScript(this.href);
    return false;
  });
});
```

This is the view:

```
<div id="entidades"><%= render "page" %></div>
```

and the partial is a standard each with the will_paginate links at the bottom.

And I created the `index.js.erb`

```
alert("ajax!");
$("#entidades").html("<%= escape_javascript(render("page")) %>");
```

No alert message is thrown whenever i click in the links. I can't get it to work. Anyone knows the problem?

Comment: try instead `.live("click"..` use `.click(..` and check that `$("#entidades .pagination a")` is exactly what you expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the issue is likely with the way you're calling the Ajax call:

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
$(document).on("click", "#entidades .pagination a", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.getScript(this.href);
    alert("ajax");
});
```

You may also wish to look about the role of `Turbolinks` in this. One of the major issues with Rails development with JS is that your application's JS calls will be interrupted by Turbolinks.

Turbolinks basically loads `<body>` of a new page, leaving the `<head>` intact. This means if you're going to use things like `$(document).ready` and `$(function(){`, you'll have to wrap them in `Tuborlinks`-compatible calls (typically the [`Turbolinks events`](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks#events)):

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
var your_function = function() {
   // calls here
};
$(document).on("page:load ready", your_function);
```

Comment: still nothing. no alert. no nothing

Comment: Console logs? Where is the JS stored? Do you have the relevant links on your page?

Comment: the index.js.erb is stored in the same folder as the index.html.erb. the application.js is in assets/javascripts folder. I use the will_paginate links.

Comment: Console logs? Rails logger? Saying  "it doesn't work" does nothing to help me diagnose the issue

Comment: wait! it worked. I mistakenly had the code in the mid of the application.js file. as soon as I noticed this I moved it to the bottom as it should be and it worked.